# How to handle redirects in Express application with Reverse Proxy

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two Express powered NodeJS applications that are being served by Nginx. One application is a RESTful API, that is consumed by an Angular SPA and the other one is an Admin portal. This is something I'm trying to achieve here:

```
location / {
  # Serves Client Side Angular Application
}

location /api {
  # Serves RESTful Application
}

location /admin {
  # Serves Admin Portal
}
```

Here is my complete configuration for nginx:

```
server { 
server_name localhost;
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
index index.html;

location / { 
    expires -1; 
    add_header Pragma "no-cache"; 
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"; 
    root /var/www/example/client/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404; 
}

location /admin/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3010/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    rewrite /admin/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host/admin/;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
} 

location /api { 
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3011;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

Both of the NodeJS application utilizes forever and run on their defined ports, perfectly.

The problem I'm facing with my admin application, when I try to hit `http://example.com/admin` it redirects me to `http://example.com/login` when it should redirect me to `http://example.com/admin/login`. I tried to solve this issue by adding a middleware to the admin application, like:

```
app.use('*', function (req, res, next) {
 if(process.env.target === 'dev'){
   if(req.originalUrl.indexOf('/admin') > -1){
     res.redirect('/admin' + req.url);
   }
   next();
 }
});
```

But this doesn't work. How should I handle this situation? Is there anyway nginx can handle application redirects? If not, how should I handle it in application for different environments(Dev, Staging, Prod etc)? I'm using nginx 1.4.6, node 0.12.2 and express 4.12.2. I have no issue if I have to add any 3rd party module in my application but I'd prefer if there is an nginx solution for my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What you're trying to do is definitely feasible. Just to confirm, are you serving hosting port 3010 and 3011 on two separate express apps?

Comment: Are you showing us your complete nginx config? Where do you configure the `proxy_pass` for your `/*` routes, eg `/login` ?

Comment: @AndrewLavers Yes. They are two separate applications. And this is my complete nginx config. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your nginx config is the rewrite for the `/admin` route:

```
rewrite /admin/(.*) /$1 break;
```

With this rule in place your admin portal node app doesn't know that its paths are all hosted off of a `/admin` root, so if your app does a redirect relative what it thinks is root, eg `res.redirect('/login')`, it makes sense that it would send the browser to `localhost/login`.

An alternative would be to remove your nginx `rewrite` and just make the admin portal aware of this `/admin` path. That way you have the option of redirecting to a *relative* path, like this: `res.redirect('login')` which tells express to take the current request's path into account. You can use the `express.Router` to make this cleaner, like this for example:

```
var adminRoutes = express.Router()
    .get('/', function(req, res) {
        if(!req.user) {
            // Will redirect to /admin/login
            res.redirect('login');
        } else {
            res.send('Hello');
        }
    })
    .get('/login', login);

// Tell express to host all routes above under a common /admin root
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
```

If on the other hand there's a better reason why you must have the nginx rewrite, you can always just include the `/admin` root manually for all of your app's redirects. You could provisionally append this mount path by reading it from a custom header set by`proxy_set_header`. For example:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.mountedAt = req.headers['X-Mounted-At'];
    next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(path.join(res.mountedAt, '/login'));
});
```

Comment: Removing the redirect directive doesn't work for me. And for the last option you provided, do I have to use `res.redirect(path.join(res.mountedAt, '/login'));` everywhere I redirect the user?

Comment: If you're redirecting to another admin page located under /admin, yes.

Comment: Did this fix your issue? Im in a similar situation where my nginx reverse proxy is sending all `/app` requests to my nodejs application. The problem being that once the Angular Index and core.js are loaded in the browser, calls to the nodejs REST API are missing the `/app/` prefix needed for nginx to route the requests. Im just getting a `Cannot GET /api/endpoint` where it should be hitting `/app/api/endpoint`

Comment: any one know the solution? I'm in same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by combining Andrew Lavers's first solution with

```
        location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass          https://127.0.0.1:3010/admin/;
    }
```